# How can I convert a string of codepoints to the string it represents?

Tags: ruby

I have a string (in Ruby) like this:

```
626c6168
```

(that is 'blah' without the quotes)

How do I convert it to 'blah'? Note that these are variable lengths, and also they aren't always letters and numbers. (They're being stored in a database, not being printed.)

Answer (score 4):

[`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206)

```
['626c6168'].pack('H*')
# => "blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `hex` to convert each character:

```
"626c6168".scan(/../).map{ |c| c.hex.chr }.join
```

This gives `blah`.